# Hibernate - Query columns map into object, the rest of the columns set to null or default value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, jdbctemplate

Basically if we want to query specific columns, we do this:

```
Query query =
session.createQuery("SELECT tr.review from TravelReview as tr");

List<String> reviews = query.list();
```

And if we want the original object (`TravelReview`) instead of `List of String`, we do this:

```
String QUERY = "SELECT new City(tr.title, tr.review ) from TravelReview as tr";

List<City> cities = session.createQuery(QUERY).list();
```

I found it very troublesome to purposely create a `Java constructor` for the purpose above. (It will end up I have many `constructors` for this.)

Is there a way to map the selected columns automatically and return the original object (`TravelReview`), only the attributes that match the selected columns have values, the rest of the attributes will be `null` (or default value)? Basically something like `Spring JdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper` which is very useful and convenient.